# Update a table when an specific column of another table is updated using trigger in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am using this trigger:

```
create trigger UpdateCustomerOnWholeSellerIdChange
on Invoice after update
as
begin
    set nocount on;
    if update(WholeSellerId)
    begin
        update Customer
        set Customer.WholeSellerId = d.WholeSellerId
        from deleted d
        where d.CustomerId = Customer.CustomerId
    end
end
```

What I am trying to accomplish is: each `CustomerId` has his own `WholeSellerId` meaning each `Customer` has their own salesman. In the `Invoice` table, each `Invoice` has its own `CustomerId` and `WholeSellerId`.

So when I update the `WholeSellerId` in the `Invoice` table, I would like to update the `WholeSellerId` of the `Customer` table as well to the `WholeSellerId` of the `Invoice` table.

With my code above, even when I update my `WholeSellerId` in the `Invoice` table, it doesn't update the `Customer`'s `WholeSellerId`.

Your help is appreciated.

Comment: What's meant to happen if an `UPDATE` affects more than one invoice for the same customer and updates `WholeSellerId` to different values?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are using `deleted` table as source, which contain data BEFORE your update run. Replace it with `inserted` table which have the new data.

[MSDN - Use the inserted and deleted Tables](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191300.aspx)